# VERY strange behavior on createobject("HTMLFILE")!

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, createobject

I don't understand why I'm getting this strange behavior!
When creating and assigning the htmlfile object the function gives back a blank object ("nothing") and when I am running the code line by line it just runs automatically even when I don't press F8 to run the next line...
It gives no error whatsoever!
Any ideas as to what might be happening?

Line where the strange behavior starts: `Set htmlObj = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")`

```
Public Function XMLHTTP_Request(Method As String, URL As String, Optional PostData As String, Optional StrCookie As String) As HTMLDocument

Dim oXMLHTTP As Object, htmlObj as object
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
oXMLHTTP.Open Method, URL, False
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookies", StrCookie

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
oXMLHTTP.send (PostData)
On Error GoTo 0

While oXMLHTTP.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
While oXMLHTTP.Status <> 200: DoEvents: Wend

Set htmlObj = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")

htmlObj.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText
Set XMLHTTP_Request = htmlObj

End Function
```

Comment: *Hyper-markup-text-language* ?

Comment: @pnuts: ok, removed it.

Comment: @Jeeped Yes, HTMLDocument.

Comment: My apologies if I came across as unclear. Specifically, you have **HMTL**FILE in the title, not **HTML**FILE.

Comment: Is there a reason that you've opted not to include the *Microsoft XML 6.0* and *Microsoft HTML object library* references and use early binding? The late binding without a static object variable will slow things down significantly on repeated calls to the function.

Comment: The reason is ignorance. :/ how do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118653/discussion-between-jony-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated calls to the function will cause multiple calls to the [CreateObject function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264813.aspx). The  oXMLHTTP and htmlObj object vars could be made static or library references could be included and the variable declaration changed to Early Binding.

Early binding requires that the following non-default library references are added through the VBE's Tools ► References command.

- Microsoft HTML Object Library
- Microsoft Internet Controls
- Microsoft XML 6.0 (your own version may vary slightly).

Module1 code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Debug.Print Left(XMLHTTP_Request("http//example.com").body.innerText, 512)
End Sub

Public Function XMLHTTP_Request(URL As String, _
                                Optional Method As String = "POST", _
                                Optional PostData As String = "", _
                                Optional StrCookie As String = "") As HTMLDocument
    Dim oXMLHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim htmlObj As New HTMLDocument

    oXMLHTTP.Open Method, URL, False
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Cookies", StrCookie

    oXMLHTTP.send PostData

    If oXMLHTTP.Status <> 200 Then Exit Function

    htmlObj.body.innerHTML = oXMLHTTP.responseText

    Set XMLHTTP_Request = htmlObj

End Function
```

Running the `main()` sub procedure will output the first 512 characters of the web page's text to the Immediate window ([Ctrl]+G).